# Dataweave - Replace value of a field in an object

Tags: java, mule, overwrite, dataweave

I have a `Java Object` as **input** payload:

```
{
"name"="Michael",
"surname"="Alpha",
"mail"="demo@gmail.com",
"gender"="Male"
}
```

I want change the gender value **keeping the rest of the message**:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
gender: if(payload.gender == "Male") "" else payload.gender
```

But it return only the gender field. 
**How can I solve that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dataweave script needs to match your output structure and you are only outputting a single gender field.

One quick way yo just modify the current payload is using `payload ++`.

If your payload is a map/object it will just replace the key if it exists or adds it if not. Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload ++ {gender: (if (payload.gender == "male") ""  else payload.gender)}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dataweave script can be simplified since 4.3.0 Runtime version with the followed way:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload update {
       case .gender -> if(payload.gender == "Male") "" else payload.gender
       
}
```

Example: [example changing field value Mule 4.3](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/anypoint-platform/update-fields-with-dataweave/)

Link doc: [change value Mule 4.3](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-cookbook-change-value-of-a-field)